# Service angularjs is not waiting for succes function to finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service which is not waiting On success function to get called in controller. The compiler is parsing the lines after my call from service and that is not what I want. When I go in debug mode I have my data there only after 10 ms or something like that

```
.factory('myService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
var deferObject,
    myMethods = {

        getDepartments: function(d) {
            console.log("Am ajuns");
            var allDepartments=[];
            var promise=$http.get("http://localhost:8087" + "/projects/"+d );
            var deferObject = deferObject || $q.defer();
            console.log("Am ajuns2");
            promise.then(

                // OnSuccess function
                function(answer){
                    console.log("Am ajuns3");
                    // This code will only run if we have a successful promise.
                    deferObject.resolve(answer);
                            var setDepartments = new Set();

                            for (var i = 0; i < answer.data.length; i++) {
                                setDepartments.add(answer.data[i].department);

                            }

                            setDepartments.forEach(function (value) {
                                var department = {name: value};
                                allDepartments.push(department);

                            });
                    console.log(allDepartments);
                    return allDepartments;
                },
                // OnFailure function
                function(reason){
                    // This code will only run if we have a failed promise.
                    deferObject.reject(reason);
                });

            return allDepartments;
        },
        getData: function(d) {
            var promise=$http.get("http://localhost:8087" + "/projects/"+d )
             var deferObject = deferObject || $q.defer();

            promise.then(
                // OnSuccess function
                function(answer){

                    // This code will only run if we have a successful promise.
                    deferObject.resolve(answer);
                },
                // OnFailure function
                function(reason){
                    // This code will only run if we have a failed promise.
                    deferObject.reject(reason);
                });

            return deferObject.promise;
        }

    };

return myMethods;

}]);
```

Comment: as your getData, getDepartments need to return a promise.

Comment: Why are you sharing the same `deferObject` across multiple promises? I can forse issue if you call both your factory methods simultaneously whilst both requests are still processing. Just return the `$http` call. You can't return out of an promise `.then` like that, the calling code has moved on since initiating it. By the time the promise resolves there is nothing to `return` to. Thats why you uses promises everywhere, not mix and match. Then when you return from one promise its is given to the next in the chain.

Comment: I understand @ste2425 , should I return only the http get reponse ?

Comment: Sadly i can't write a full answer so comment will have to do, very briefly you return from your service/factory `$http.get("http://localhost:8087" + "/projects/"+d )` then in you calling code you can do `myService.getData().then(d => console.log(d));`. Essentially `$http` returns a promise, so return that out of you service to chain on in your controller etc so you can be notified once the network call is complete. You can also nest promise chains, etc for complex async workflows.

Comment: Ok  @ste2425 , thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using q.all , which is waiting for every request to finish and only after that the program is going further.